# How to get windows logon credentials from a Swing application?

Tags: java, windows, swing, authentication, single-sign-on

How would I go about getting the Windows user credentials from a Swing application?

I am working on an internal (corporate) Swing application. Currently the user has to login to the application using a login screen, which then connects to an app server which authenticates the user against the company LDAP server.

Since the user has already logged in to his workstation using the same credentials, is there any way that a Swing application can get these credentials from Windows itself and then automatically log the user in (SSO)? I know this is possible because I have seen some other applications do it, but I don't know how to go about doing this with Swing/Java.

Comment: You certainly will not be able to retrieve the users password, that's not stored on Windows (at least, I really hope it isn't...). So no chance for full credentials.

Comment: I don't need the password, I just need to know that the user is authenticated against the domain. Both Windows and the server side are authenticating against the same LDAP server.

Comment: Ah, ok, but you said 'credentials' and that's username+password.

Comment: how does one login to windows when one is not connected on network; surely it stores the password for the respective userid.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of solution did you end to?

Comment: @Touko - we never followed through on this feature, but the answer below seemed like good information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are similar questions on SO that look like interesting (so this question might be a duplicate):

- [How do I access Windows credentials from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126684/how-do-i-access-windows-credentials-from-java)
- [Java Active Directory Integrated Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010356/java-active-directory-integrated-windows-authentication)

IMHO, read carefully Kohsuke's blog posts ([here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/06/more_active_dir.html) and [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/01/active%5Fdirector.html)) and the [Single-Sign-On in Java Platform using Active Directory](http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/) article, they contain very valuable informations.

But you need to dig the whole thing a bit further.